# Arraylist as Message when sending mail

Tags: java, sendmail

I have this arraylist;

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I have populate this arraylist from some DB queries and i must send this list as e-mail.

```
public void sendMail(ArrayList carriers) throws Exception {  
        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setHostName("mail.test.com.tr");
        email.setSmtpPort(587);
        email.setAuthentication("testuser@mail.test.com.tr","testuserpass");
        email.setSSLOnConnect(false);
        email.setFrom("testuser@mail.test.com.tr");
        email.setSubject("Test Information List");
        email.setMsg("Last 1 hour Information;\n"+carriers);
        email.addTo("test@mail.test.com.tr");
        email.send();
        System.out.println("email sended succesfully.");
        }
```

When i call this sendMail(list); method mail came to my mailbox succesfully. But all strings in this list showing side by side in message body normally. I want all strings align vertically.Let me explain;

```
Now;
trying1, trying2, trying3

Desired format;
trying1
trying2
trying3
```

How can i handle it?

**--SOLVED--**

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(Object carrier : carriers)
b.append(carrier).append("\n");  

String carriersString = b.toString();
```

Above lines added to sendMail() method, beginning of code. And below lines editing to;

```
email.setMsg("Last 1 hour Information;\n"+carriersString);
```

Thanks to @Icewind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manually concatenate the strings to your desired format. The default `toString()` method will concatenate the values by a `comma`.

Something like this:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(String carrier : carriers)
    b.append(carrier).append("\n");

String carriersString = b.toString();
```

or with StringUtils in apache commons (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
String carriersString = StringUtils.join(carriers, "\n");
```

...snip...

```
email.setMsg("Last 1 hour Information;\n"+carriersString);
```

Comment: I edit my question as solved. Thanks for your solution Icewind.